# Extract a part of line from logs

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have the following lines in a log file:

```
<ROW USER_GID="TEST 1" FLOW="Norm" SEQUENCE="9"/>
<ROW USER_GID="TEST 2" FLOW="Norm" SEQUENCE="2"/>
<ROW USER_GID="TEST 3" FLOW="Norm" SEQUENCE="2"/>
```

I am trying to extract the value of `USER_GID` in each line. Can I accomplish the same using `grep`/`awk` or `sed` command.

In the above case the output should return:

```
TEST 1 
TEST 2
TEST 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can perform this operation via `sed`, you might be better off using an XML parser to get the right lines for you.

That said, you can use the following sed command, assuming all your data is in the same format.

`sed -n 's/.*USER_GID="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' log_file`

Comment: Thank you! This works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Done by below awk command

```
awk -F '"' '/USER_GID/{print $2}' filename
```

output

```
TEST 1
TEST 2
TEST 3
```